# ASP login code not submitting

Tags: html, sql, forms, authentication, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a login page powered by asp and sql. After clicking submit, the form will not even trigger (i.e. the error message will not even display if the fields are blank)

Here is my code:

```vbs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Query
</title>
<link href="http://hr-computing/public/AlexS/Tests/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <body>
<div id="main">

<%
username = ""
password = ""
ErrorMessage = ""

if request.form <> "" then
   username = Request.Form("firstname")
   password = Request.Form("password")
  if username = "" or password = "" then
     ErrorMessage = "You must specify a username and password."
  else
     set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 conn.Open ="{private}
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.Open "Select firstname, PASSWORD FROM teachers WHERE firstname = '" & firstname & "'", conn
    if rs.EOF = false then 
      if rs.fields("Password") = password then
         Response.Redirect("http://hr-computing/public/AlexS/Tests/default.asp")
      end if
    end if 
  ErrorMessage = "Login failed"
  end if 
end if
%>



<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="http://hr-computing/public/AlexS/Tests/login.asp">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Log In to Your Account</legend>
<ol>
<li>
 <label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
</li>
<li>
<label>Password:</label>
 <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</li>
<li>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</li>
</ol>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone tell me what is wrong, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you print out your error message? It doesn't look like you have that displayed anywhere. Classic ASP is kind of painful about this stuff - but somewhere you need a

```
<%= ErrorMessage %>
```

call to display the login error.

Answer (score -3):

As you are using asp.net so for validating username and password for empty you can use required field validator. Be sure to set validation group to both the textbox as well as submit button.

Comment: Ok so sorry to sound stupid (im new to asp) could you possibly give me some example code to fix my problem?

Comment: Except the example is not using ASP.Net - it's using asp-classic/vbscript.

Comment: Yeh thats why I was a bit confused by ashutosh's answer, can you see my problem?